# Unit Tests for modules in lib folder # Rails applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a module defined in the lib folder . The module is included in one of the model files.

In order to test the code in the module , do i need to write separate test cases for the module by creating a new unit test for the module , or can i create unit tests for the model file ,which uses the methods defined in the module.

Right now , i have a model file called assignment.rb in which i have included the module called File. The File module has some methods called submit_file.

I am using these methods in the unit test for the model file by including the module in the assignment_test.rb  and all the tests currently pass.

Should this suffice the testing of the module ?

Since the module is in the lib folder , is it necessary for me to use include  in the assignment_test.rb ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a separate module called File?  Presumably it is because this module will be included in several different models?  In which case it would probably be sensible to test it separately. It might also be better to test it separately if there is a lot of code involved and the tests for the assignment model are getting long and difficult to read.  However, if neither of these applies I see no reason to split the tests into two, provided of course that the File module is thoroughly tested in the context of the Assignment model

Comment: The module is right now being used for only one model and in future we would wanna extend it to be used in other models as well. Hence , we have a separate module for File which will be used later across various classes. For now we have 10 test cases in the assignment_test for the model and all of them seemed to execute well. Hence , we did not until now find the need to write separate tests for the module alone since all its methods are tested in the unit test.

Comment: In that case the only reason I can think of why you might consider testing the File module separately is for clarity.  If someone is looking for the tests of the File module, it will not be obvious which model they are in.

Comment: So , i went ahead a created testcases for the module in the test/helper folder. However , when i am trying to call the same from the assignment_test.rb. I am creating a testcase in the assignment_test.rb for which i use the testcase of the module. However it seems to fail since it says it is an undefined method. What are the exact i need to be doin for including the helper file in the unit test ?

Comment: I think your problem may be to do with naming here - Try renaming the File module to Myfile, put that in lib/myfile, and then using require 'myfile' in your test setup